# Icons missing on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: debian, browser

For the last couple of days, some of the items normally displayed in the top border of the Stack Exchange sites have been missing on my computer.

Above the site logo are three fields: links to Stack Exchange sites, “Inbox,” and “Recent Achievements.” If I hover over the area, it turns from black to dark grey and displays a hint, and I can click on the area and it works, but the icons don't show.

It does this with several different browsers, so it isn’t browser-specific. However, the sites display normally on another computer. It appears to be something in Debian (Wheezy), probably from a recent update, that is preventing the icons from being shown in any browser.

What should I look for?

Comment: you could check you don't have http://cdn.sstatic.net blocked anywhere - that's where the icons are hosted

Comment: Hey, it's sacrilegious to downvote a question about correctly viewing this site. :-)  If it is due to a Debian update, the problem is likely to affect others.  There should also be a specific cause that someone with the right knowledge can recognize from the symptoms.

Comment: @Tetsujin - This is across browsers, including Konquerer, so it isn't in a browser or add-in setting.  Is there somewhere in Debian that this could happen?  I do get the Super User logo.

Comment: Try a different DNS server.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - Where do I find that (router setting)? How do I set it to another one and what settings to use?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Defining_the_.28DNS.29_Nameservers, http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/a/free-public-dns-servers.htm

Comment: Do you see the 'star' icon or 'tick' under the question? They're from the same file as the logo. The header icons, 'answers' 'rep', 'review' etc are from a different file.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I see the star, so apparently that's not it.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem starting yesterday (Windows, lastest Firefox). In my case it was cause by the FF addon Adblock Edge. Adding "@@||stackoverflow.com^$document" and "@@||superuser.com^$document" as exception filters fixed it.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - A little knowledge is a dangerous thing; even less knowledge is even more dangerous.  Followed the instruction in the link.  Any change to the method setting (Automatic (DHCP) vs. Automatic (DHCP) addresses only + OpenDNS server), in either direction then restarting the browser, yields the normal appearance. However, refresh the page and the icons disappear again.

Comment: @DavidPostill - It happens in Konqueror, also, so I assumed it was not browser-specific (Konqueror doesn't do add-ins and disabling its own ad blocker didn't help).  But I tried your suggestion in Firefox (I have Adblock Plus and I disabled it for this site).  Darn, if you ain't right.  That fixed it.

Comment: @DavidPostill - why don't you post the solution as an answer, you deserve the rep.

Comment: Done, with added extras, thx

Comment: ah, so I was on the right lines, but lacked the necessary web-fu ;-) Nice one @DavidPostill

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd already fixed it yesterday with the exception filters, but your comment above re `sstatic.net` allowed me to find the root cause. So thanks to you :)

Comment: @DavidPostill Welcome - I've binned some of my extraneous comment to tidy up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem starting yesterday (Windows, lastest Firefox). In my case it was cause by the FF addon [Adblock Edge](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/adblock-edge/).

Adding `@@||stackoverflow.com^$document` and `@@||superuser.com^$document` as exception filters fixed it.

Further investigation (searching for filters containing `sstatic.net` as per comment by Tetsujin) shows that [Fanboys Social Blocking List](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) was updated 13/11/2014 and now includes the following filter:

```
@@||sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.png$domain=askubuntu.com|mathoverflow.net|serverfault.com|stackapps.com|stackexchange.com|stackoverflow.com|superuser.com
```

I've now disabled this filter ...

Edit (by fixer1234):

Let me expand this for anyone else with another related problem; it looks like the common denominator is the Fanboys Social Blocking List.  About a week ago. Firefox updated itself on a Windows computer to V33 and updated add-ins along with it.  Super User then would not work and displayed a banner about needing Java or Java Script, I forget which.  It turns out the issue was the same.  Disabling the ad and tracker blockers for this site (Adblock Plus and Ghostery, in my case), eliminated the problem.